# Разметка CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

[image: Нужно]

Есть круг, изображение и текст. Нужно разметить так, как на картинке. Оформление элементов не учитывать.

```
<div class="test">
<p><strong>Lorem<br>ipsum<br>dolor</strong></p>
<div id="circle"></div>
<img src="img/money.png" alt="Деньги">
</div>
```

Comment: ну дак разместите, если нужно. А если проблема какая-то возникает, то опишите ее.

Comment: все сползает куда-то, приходится использовать margin ко всем элементам, а вообще я новичок, еще не опытный :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу посоветовать вам **Flex**, вот пример с его использованием:

```css
.content {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: right;
}

.circle {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: grey;
}

.img {
    height: 35px;
}

.text {
    font-family: Arial, serif;
    font-size: 28pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="circle">
        <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Stack_Overflow_logo.svg/1280px-Stack_Overflow_logo.svg.png"
             alt="Деньги">
    </div>
    <spam class="text"><strong>Lorem<br>ipsum<br>dolor</strong></spam>
</div>
```